# Gallery moving all over

Tags: html, css

I have a gallery plugin in my main page -> http://tranceil.fm

It is set to these css rules:

```
box_skitter {
    position: relative;
    width: 985px;
    height: 560px;
    margin: 52px auto 32px;
    background: black;
}
```

If you take a look at the website, the gallery is not exactly aligned. I want to move it a bit to the right. But whenever I try doing that it looses its grip and moves all around if I resize the window..

How can I move it without making it go along with a resize?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
.box_skitter {
position: relative;
width: 985px;
height: 560px;
margin: 52px auto 32px;
background: black;
left: 19px;
}
```

Comment: wow...i don't know how that worked..but it did..:) that simple. well thank you jlcd!

Comment: Please "tick" this guy's answer. It's the least you could do!

Comment: I did...i had 5 minuets time-out on the ticking for some reason..i know how to appreciate guys like you :)

Answer (score 2):

Use left property instead of margin

```
 box_skitter {
  position:relative;
  width: 985px;
  height: 560px;
  left: 52px;//will move the div to 52px right
  background: black;}
```

EDIT: Since box_skitter is not an HTML element , so if it's ID then do

```
 #box_skitter {
      position:relative;
      width: 985px;.....
```

If it's class then

```
.box_skitter {
  position:relative;
  width: 985px;....
```

Comment: @Trance84 may be you are not adding it properly